# Xamarin Forms get WebView content as string

Tags: android, webview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to get the content of a WebView as a string?

I tried using:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Constants.LOGIN_URL);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

But I didn't get what i wanted because the webview stores the sessions etc.

I want a method to get the data of a logged in user from a website if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to download the content of the `WebView` in the context of a logged in user, you may want to try injecting `JavaScript` into the `WebView` and then having the `JavaScript` send code back to a `C#` method.

An example of something like this can be found in XLabs' `Hybrid WebView` (which is the example I used to call `JavaScript` from `C#` methods).

Have a look at the URL below. You will need to create a custom renderer for each platform that you support but that should just be a matter of copying and pasting from the link below.

Once you have you custom renderer all set, you can simply pull all of the `HTML` using a `JavaScript` method.

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView

Reply back if you run into any road blocks.

Comment: Sadly I found another way of doing what I wanted anyway hope this answer helps the other users :)

Comment: Thanks for the up vote. Out of curiosity, how did you end up solving it?

Comment: I needed to add the logged in user name so i put in a section a small WebView that links to a page that displays only the name. When I click it i use webview.Navigating method to change my pages. Yea I know is bad but they wanted me to make it this way :).